# How to go from raw Bitmap data to SDL Surface or Texture?

Tags: c++, bitmap, textures, sdl, surface

I'm using a library called Awesomium and it has the following function:

```
void Awesomium::BitmapSurface::CopyTo   (   unsigned char *     dest_buffer, // output
int     dest_row_span, // input that I can select
int     dest_depth, // input that I can select
bool    convert_to_rgba, // input that I can select
bool    flip_y // input that I can select
)       const
Copy this bitmap to a certain destination. Will also set the dirty bit to False.

Parameters
dest_buffer A pointer to the destination pixel buffer.
dest_row_span   The number of bytes per-row of the destination.
dest_depth  The depth (number of bytes per pixel, is usually 4 for BGRA surfaces and 3 for BGR surfaces).
convert_to_rgba Whether or not we should convert BGRA to RGBA.
flip_y  Whether or not we should invert the bitmap vertically.
```

This is great because it gives me an `unsigned char *   dest_buffer` which contains raw bitmap data. I've been trying for several hours to convert this raw bitmap data into some sort of usable format that I can use in SDL but I'm having trouble. =[ Is there any way I can load it into a SDL texture or surface? It would be ideal to have examples for both but if I only get one example (either texture or surface), that is sufficient and I will be very grateful. :) I tried to use SDL_LoadBMP_RW but that crashed. I'm not even sure if I should be using that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SDL_LoadBMP_RW` is for loading an image in the BMP file format. And it expects an `SDL_RWops*`, which is a file stream, not a pixel buffer. The function you want is [SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom). I believe this call should work for your purposes:

```
SDL_Surface* surface =
    SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(
      pixels,       // dest_buffer from CopyTo
      width,        // in pixels
      height,       // in pixels
      depth,        // in bits, so should be dest_depth * 8
      pitch,        // dest_row_span from CopyTo
      Rmask,        // RGBA masks, see docs
      Gmask,
      Bmask,
      Amask
    );
```